# Documentation for older versions of Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If I am working on a long running or old project which uses an older version of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), where can I find the documentation? (upgrading is not always the easiest option).

Comment: I've used bootstrap since it first came out, and I'm not sure there is a need. Is there something in particular that is bothering you?

Comment: Yep. That if I didn't update last week then we would have no documentation when making updates.

Comment: I think maybe the customized download page should give you the option to download documentation in the bundle.

Comment: It looks like they are only doing fixes and plan to maintain backward compatibility. You could always do a wget on the few pages and save them locally.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is one website that publishes all versions of the doc :

http://bootstrapdocs.com/

But in case this website goes down, as said before, you can download the doc bundled with the source on github : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tags

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a few people over at the GitHub repo are asking the [same](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1630) [question](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1527). Head over the to [tags in the GIT repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tags) and download the bundle associated with the version you require. The download contains the source and documentation.

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v2.1.0
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v2.0.4
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v2.0.3
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v2.0.2
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v2.0.1
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v2.0.0
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v1.4.0
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v1.3.0
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v1.2.0
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v1.1.1
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v1.1.0
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/v1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

[Twitter bootstrap release page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/) contains links to particular version archives and a changelog. Each archive contains docs folder.

The site from the accepted answer wasn't updated since v2.3.1.